# how to add custom property type in greendao

Tags: android, greendao

I am a new android programmer.
Currently I am using Greendao. I noticed that it only provides certain add properties methods. I am wondering if there is any way to add other custom property types(For example, a Picture) to my entity?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Since you are new to stackoverflow: Don't forget to accept answers, that solve your problem/question. If an answer is not sufficient or leaves open questions: Feel free to write a comment.

Answer (score 3):

Since greendao is open source you may very well implement such custom property types and map them to the basic SQLite-datatypes. But you shouldn't!

1. If you do you will have to merge your solution into the greendao sources everytime you want to use a new version/release of greendao.
2. Greendao covers as far as I know already all SQLite-datatypes with its properties.

To save pictures or other complex data you can use the `ByteArray`-property:

```
Entity entity = schema.addEntity("MyTest");
entity.addByteArrayProperty("picture");
```

In the `KEEP-SECTION` of your entity you can add conversion methods:

```
public static byte[] bitmap2bytes(Bitmap bitmap) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
    return stream.toByteArray();
}

public static Bitmap bytes2Bitmap(byte[] byteArray) {
    return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, 0, byteArray.length);
}
```

And finally use:

```
myTestObj.setPicture(MyTest.bitmap2bytes(bitmap));
```

and

```
Bitmap bmp = MyTest.bytes2bitmap(myTestObj.getPicture());
```

**Remark:** In case of pictures or other big data you can follow the approach to store the data as file on the device and store the path to that file in your database using String-property.